# Convert JSP Session to an ArrayList<MyClass> error every code has changed

Tags: java, jsp, session, arraylist

I create an `ArrayList` based on `ProductData` class on my JSP, this list represents as a shopping cart.

```
ArrayList<ProductData> cartList = new ArrayList<ProductData>();
ProductData data = new ProductData(productId, productName, productPrice, productAmmount);
cartList.add(data);
```

After that, I'm storing my `ArrayList` to JSP `session`, cause I don't want my `ArrayList` lost when I leave this page.

```
session.setAttribute("cartList", cartList);
```

On the other section, I get the `session` and convert it as an `ArrayList` of `ProductData`
(I check if the session is null or not for sure)

```
ArrayList<ProductData> cartList = session.getAttribute("cartList") == null ? new ArrayList<ProductData>() : (ArrayList<ProductData>)session.getAttribute("cartList");
```

It works well on the first run. But, every time I changes the code on my page (and I'm not modifying my class declaration), the servlet thows an error: `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.jsp.MCPatisserie.cart_jsp$1ProductData`

My question is: is this a good method to implement a `class` on java servlet page?
Is this error caused by recompilation of the servlet page and the `session` object didn't match with my `ArrayList` anymore?
Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you change your JSP, the container recompiles it to a new Java source file, and recompiles this new Java source file to a new class. It seems you have defined a Java class inside the JSP. So this class is also regenerated and recompiled. So the object in the session has a class that is not the same as the one recreated.

You shouldn't have Java code in JSPs. And definitely not class definitions. ProductData should be defined in its own .java file, like any other class.

Comment: Oh my guess is right.. Thank you so much..
So, I sould not declare any class on my JSP? Can I define my own java class and import it on my JSP? Or it should be packaged?

Comment: Of course you can. The class files should be under the WEB-INF/classes directory of the webapp (respecting the package structure, of course), or in a jar stored in WEB-INF/lib. But JSPs should not contain Java code and import classes. Learn about the MVC pattern, the JSTL and the JSP EL, choose an MVC framework (Stripes or Spring MVC, for example), and forget about Java code in JSPs.